# How does Amazon compress its images so well?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, file-size

I'm working on reducing the size of my dom content,

As an example, Amazon's current home page graphic is 1500x600px, while remaining only 88.8K ([link](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img18/home/katespade/gw/kate_spade_gw_desktop_hero_1x._CB436256638_.jpg)) and shows very little jpg artifacting. How are they able to compress it so well? The best our team has been able to achieve in photoshop for a similarly sized graphic is ~200K.

Comment: I don't know what source file you have but try to make indexed picture (or save to PNG with limited colors) and then to jpg.

Comment: Without providing an image it's impossible to say, maybe yours has more colors and details. Also note that Photoshop uses not so smart conversion methods and there're solutions (tinyJPG for instance) that may make jpg files smaller while retaining better quality.

Comment: That's a question for Amazon software engineers to answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question cannot be meaningfully answered by anyone other than the people at Amazon who put up the graphic in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPG artifacts are most often noticeable at the edges of large areas containing similar color... there are *very* few such areas in your particular sample image.

However, there **are** some considerable artifacts.

[image]

What Amazon uses, I'm afraid would require Amazon to answer.

Ultimately, the quality of the final jpg depends highly upon the image itself and any setting used when saving.

The jpg format uses a **lossy** compression scheme. You should try and avoid **ever** saving a jpg as a jpg. Each subsequent save of a jpg as a jpg throws out more image data and further degrades any image - introducing *more* artifacts.

Comment: "depends highly upon the image itself" JPEG artifacts are very notiecable on solid color transitions. One (limited) way to mitigate this is by adding noise or "texture." In the example, the tablecloth looks like it had a pattern on it, and they may have added some sort of colored noise prior to compression.

Comment: @Yorik, but noise increases file size significantly.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. We're going to give some of these a shot.

Comment: @Wolff that is not *necessarily* true. If I were to take a tablecloth texture and overlay with low opacity on a photo of glasses on a "blown out" white tablecloth, then jammed to compression down to its lowest setting, the resulting file size would be very similar (almost identical) to one without the texture but the artifacting would be masked somewhat and the halo effect of solid transitions would have less perceptual impact.

Comment: and recall that my point is that the technique is for hiding *extra* compression.

Comment: @Yorik, OK, I see your point. Never tried that exact method. I thought you meant applying *gaussian noise* or something like that with 1 px details.